# how to update schema after adding "accepts_nested_attributes_for" to a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes

here is my model

```
class Lineup < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :artists
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :artists
  belongs_to :event
end

class Artist < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :events, :through => :lineups
  has_many :lineups
end
```

when running this in the console

```
Lineup.new(artists_attributes: [{artist_id: 1}, {artist_id: 2}])
```

the error is `ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'artists_attributes' for Lineup.` Obviously, I can't just drop something like that into a model and expect any changes to be from that alone. Do I need to run a migration for this? If so, what needs to be in it?

schema:

```
  create_table "artists", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.text     "bio"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer  "lineup_id"
    t.integer  "event_id"
  end

  add_index "artists", ["event_id"], name: "index_artists_on_event_id", using: :btree
  add_index "artists", ["lineup_id"], name: "index_artists_on_lineup_id", using: :btree

create_table "lineups", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer  "artist_id"
    t.integer  "event_id"
  end

  add_index "lineups", ["artist_id"], name: "index_lineups_on_artist_id", using: :btree
  add_index "lineups", ["event_id"], name: "index_lineups_on_event_id", using: :btree
```

Comment: Honestly I think that is all you have to do per the docs (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html). Is the relationship between `Lineups` and `Artists` one-to-many or many-to-many? Also are you using the beta version of rails 5? Otherwise it should be `ActiveRecord::Base` not `ApplicationRecord`

Comment: many-to-many. lineup can have many artists. artist can have many lineups. yes, I'm on Rails 5 beta. I'm so used to stuff like that being omitted from docs because it'd be common sense.

Comment: Do you have a join table between them as well?

Comment: I added references to each other through a migration. Also successfully seeded a `Lineup` with one `Artist` inside of it. Now I want to be able to do multiple artists inside a lineup.

Comment: If they both have_many of each other you need a join table in between them. It would help a lot if you could post your schema for Lineups, Artists, and their join table if that exists. The Artists model would be helpful as well.

Comment: ok, updated. I always create join table myself, right? even if I made references in a migration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would set it up like this

schema

```
table Lineup
  ...

table Artist
  ...

table LineupArtists
  lineup_id: Integer
  artist_id: Integer
```

models

```
class Artist < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :lineup_artists, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :lineups, through: :lineup_artists
end

class LineupArtist < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :lineup
   belongs_to :artist

   accepts_nested_attributes_for :lineup
end 

class Lineup < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :lineup_artists, inverse_of: :lineup, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :artists, through: lineup_artists

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :lineup_artists
end
```

The way you currently have it (with `Artists` having a lineup_id and `Lineups` having an artist_id) each model can only have one of the other (i.e. an `Artist` can have one lineup and vise versa). A join table gives the ability to have a many-to-many relationship.

Setting up nested attributes is a little trickier with a many-to-many but I believe what I posted should cover it. If not got some of the weirder bits from this post (https://robots.thoughtbot.com/accepts-nested-attributes-for-with-has-many-through). Hope this helps.

Comment: a lineup `has_many :lineups, through: lineup_artists`, are you sure?

Comment: Whoops should be `artists`. Changed above.

Comment: Only if you want to be able to be able to create the data relationships between `Lineups` and `Artists` in the same command as you create a `Lineup`

Comment: another question, do you think `accepts_nested_attributes_for` is still needed here? also, should I delete the `lineup_id` and `artist_id` columns from corresponding models before creating a join table?

Comment: Yeah you should probably remove those. Also I'm not sure if you need the `event_id` in either table. Rule of thumb you have a foreign key in an object if that object can only have one of the other object it's referencing, if they can have more than one there should be a join table (so if a lineup and/or artist can only have one event keep the `event_id`, otherwise you probably need a join table there too)

Comment: I was just looking back over teh schema and wondering about `event_id`. yeah, lineup can only belong to one event and artist can have multiple events through multiple corresponding lineups. I think I can figure it out from here. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace line:

```
has_many :artists
```

With this one:

```
has_many :artists, foreign_key: "lineup_id"
```